# How to authenticate an Azure Function app with a managed identity to a Azure SQL Server instance

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-active-directory

I have a Function App with a managed identity that needs to be able to execute SQL queries from a managed SQL Server instance. I've seen articles about adding users, and user managed identities to a SQL Server instance with Azure Active Directory, but I haven't seen Azure managed identities.  The managed identity doesn't show up in Azure Active Directory, so SSMS is unable to create the login. `Create failed for Login 'MyFunctionApp'.  Principal 'MyFunctionApp' could not be found or this principal type is not supported.`. Is it possible to have a managed identity added as a login to SQL Server via Azure Active Directory?  If not, what's the recommended approach, just create another login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The login is not a normal user, you need to specify that it's from external provider:

```
CREATE USER [<identity-name>] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [<identity-name>];
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER [<identity-name>];
```

more info : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-connect-msi

Comment: What should I use as the `identity-name`?  The managed identity object id?

Comment: the name of the managed identity (which usually is the same as your app service name)

Comment: So in the case of a deployment slot, the managed identity name would be `MyFunctionApp/MySlot`?  I'm receiving `Principal 'MyFunctionApp/MySlot' could not be found or this principal type is not supported.`

Comment: I've never used in a deployment slot. But in the production one, it works the way I've described

Comment: Testing everything now, but `MyFunctionApp/slots/MySlot` was accepted.